# Adding custom colours to Summernote

Tags: jquery, summernote

In Summernote, there is an option to add colours to the foreground and background but these colours are "fixed" - I am trying to figure out how to add additional custom colours to those selections either by way of a colour picker or even just as selectable options.

My code looks like this currently:

```
    $('#sn').summernote({
        toolbar: [
            ['style', ['style']],
            ['font', ['bold', 'italic'],
            ['fontname', ['fontname']],
            ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
            ['color', ['color'],
            ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']]
          ]
    });
```

I found a message on Github eluding to how to do this at https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/269

However I cannot figure out what I need to do?

I have tried:

```
    $('#sn').summernote({
        toolbar: [
            ['style', ['style']],
            ['font', ['bold', 'italic'],
            ['fontname', ['fontname']],
            ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
            ['color', ['color','#ffffff'],
            ['colors', [["#000000", "#ffffff"]]],
            ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']]
          ]
    });
```

but neither of these options work - any idea how I can add additional colors?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As noted in [tingham's comment](https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/269#issuecomment-339398797) the colors array is in an additional property in the summernote options object i.e.

```
$('#sn').summernote({
    colors: [
        ['red', 'green', 'blue'], //first line of colors
        ['#c4b540', '#1dd381', '#ba1cd2'] //second line of colors
    ],
    toolbar: [...]
});
```

The `colors` array is multidimensional with each level 2 array being a line in the color picker. From testing the colors don't break onto a new line automatically so you'll want to limit each line to 8 colors to keep it looking like the default.

It looks like you can use any valid CSS format for the colors: `red`, `#ff0000`, `rgb(255, 0, 0)` etc.

Answer (score 2):

In summernote.js :

```
colors: [['#444444','#000000'...],
colorsName: [['CustomColorName','Black'...],
```